# How to stop visual studio from automatically adding remove in an item group in my csproj?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a .NET 5 WPF project, in the csproj file, i have

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <ViewModelFiles Include="**\*ViewModel.cs"></ViewModelFiles>
        <Content Include="@(ViewModelFiles)">
            <DependentUpon>$([System.String]::Copy('%(FileName)').Replace('Model', '.xaml'))</DependentUpon>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```

However, whenever I add a new item into my project, the IDE automatically adds a line of remove into the csproj file. For example, after Visual\Settings\Control\InputActionViewModel.cs is added:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <ViewModelFiles Include="**\*ViewModel.cs"></ViewModelFiles>
        <ViewModelFiles Remove="Visual\Settings\Control\InputActionViewModel.cs" />
        <Content Include="@(ViewModelFiles)">
            <DependentUpon>$([System.String]::Copy('%(FileName)').Replace('Model', '.xaml'))</DependentUpon>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This is troblesome as I need to make an additional manual operation for every item I created. I would like to know how to swich off this auto generation.

**October 25, 2022 Edit**

The following is my current code

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="**\*ViewModel.cs">
      <DependentUpon>$([System.String]::Copy('%(FileName)').Replace('Model', '.xaml'))</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Please provide more informaion: VS version, a minimum but complete project file which reproduces the issue, directory structure.

Comment: @martinrhan Did you manage to resolve it or work around it somehow? I have the same issue: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/8636

Comment: @TomPažourek Try change "Include" to "Update", I just added some detail to this post.

Comment: Take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69193872/in-msbuild-how-to-set-item-metadata-dynamically-relative-to-file-name

Comment: @martinrhan Thanks. For me, the final workaround that I used was  `Condition="'$(DesignTimeBuild)' != 'true'"` in the ItemGroup around the wildcard include item...

Answer (score -2):

I think this is because this line

```
<ViewModelFiles Include="**\*ViewModel.cs"></ViewModelFiles>
```

has clarified that include the *ViewModel.cs files. And also, you are using new SDK project, the added items(files) will be included in the project automatically. So, twice, and MSBuild automatically remove the items which named *ViewModel.cs.

If you test to change names when adding items, such as ViewModelXXX.cs, or ViewXXXModel.cs, there will not be a line added.

If you test to add items first, and then add this line

```
<ViewModelFiles Include="**\*ViewModel.cs"></ViewModelFiles>
```

there will also not be a line added.

Comment: This is probably true, but you have to understand what the issue is. @martinrhan wants to extend the msbuild project, and doesn't want visual studio to work against him.